# Is it ok to use Stack Overflow content for my work?

Tags: support

Am I permitted to use Stack Overflow content for my work?  I work for a commercial software company and use content from Stack Overflow regularly to assist me in completing projects.

The Stack Overflow terms, in particular this excerpt, concern me:

> Subject to the terms and conditions of this Agreement, Stack Exchange may offer to provide the Services, as described more fully on the Network, and which are selected by Subscriber, solely for Subscriber’s own use, and not for the use or benefit of any third party

Is the company I work for a 3rd party who would benefit from using Stack Overflow?

Comment: *If it's not allowed, then I have to resign from my company right now...*

Comment: Content on SO is [posted under a Creative Commons Attribution - Share Alike license](http://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing).

Comment: Thanks for answering. still a little question. Who is the third party in this sentence: "Subject to the terms and conditions of this Agreement, Stack Exchange may offer to provide the Services, as described more fully on the Network, and which are selected by Subscriber, solely for Subscriber’s own use, and not for the use or benefit of any third party" Is it the company you work?

Comment: @yvaaar I have editing the excerpt from the TOS that you were worried about.  I believe I have captured what you are trying to ask.

Comment: This is about services, content is specifically covered in a later section of the TOS.

Comment: **In theory yes**, you only need to conform to the CC-BY-SA license. But this license won't be acceptable for most projects, so IMO the answer is **no**. I already complained to Jeff about it, but he doesn't give a damn.

Comment: @Louis the services include the offered content right?

Comment: @yvaaar In my opinion (I am not a lawyer), the TOS makes a distinction between Services and Contents such that one is not a subset of the other. Even if Contents *were* a subset of Services, an interpretive issue would arise due to the TOS being potentially interpreted in a self-contradictory way ("you can't" but "you can"). In this kind of scenario, if there *really* was a contradiction, the TOS would be interpreted in your favor. If this keeps you up at night, you should consult a lawyer.

Comment: Answers are *not* one of the services that Stack Exchange provides.  They are contributions from others and covered by the cc-by-sa license.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are reading a little too far into that sentence. It is saying that a third party cannot consume the Stack Exchange service for their own benefit.

Your company is not the third party in this situation because it is not directly involved in consuming the Stack Exchange service. You are the beneficiary of the service, and as a result it helps you do a better job.

A best practice I follow is to include attribution if I directly copy and use an *exact* piece of code. Usually though, and what makes Stack Overflow so epic, is that generalized approaches are shown through simple complete examples - and do not apply if directly copy pasted.

Here is one example though, of using the exact code I have come across and cited in my published code. This snippet is in production and being used live.

```
/*source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2117523/1026459 @broofa*/
abstract.guid = function () {
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) { var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : r & 0x3 | 0x8; return v.toString(16); });
};
```

Answer (score 8):

Like all other user generated content, any code posted on Stack Overflow is subject to the CC-Wiki license.

In consequence, the [requirement for attribution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) applies:

> Proper attribution is required if you republish any Stack Exchange content.

technically applies even to the smallest copied piece of code.

While you're not very likely to ever get in trouble if you use a piece of SO code without giving attribution (like in a comment saying, "snippet written by author .... taken from....") , it would still be a violation of the agreement and a small but real danger you'd be introducing into your code base. You don't want that for anything serious - be it a commercial project or an Open Source one. (See [SCO v. IBM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCO_v._IBM) for an example how this can come back to bite you even in an Open Source context.)

Either make sure that you are *giving* attribution to the original author in the code, or be safe by re-writing any code from SO that you'd be reusing, using your own variable names etc., just copying the concept but not the literal code.

Comment: cc-by-sa also applies to derived works.  So using different variable names etc is not a workaround, just a questionable obfuscation.

Comment: That's why I recommend writing the code again, from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

The interesting bits on SO that you'd use for your company are part of the User-Generated Content. No matter what the SO TOS would say, that content is licensed **to** SO on CC-BY-SA terms. Clause 4 renders invalid any attempted restrictions by Stack Exchange Inc.

In particular, Stack Exchange Inc is not the copyright owner of User-Generated Content and has no standing to sue you for copyright infringement.